# Foreground image becomes smaller while overlaying 1 image over another

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I am trying to create an app where user can drag 1 image over another and then that image could be saved.

I have written the following code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainImageView: UIImageView!    //Background Image
var Person: UIImageView!         //Foreground Image
var location = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
var image: UIImage!
var frontSize: CGSize!

@IBOutlet weak var overlayButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "pizza")!
    frontSize = image.size
    Person = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(90, 140, image.size.width, image.size.height))
    Person.image = image
    Person.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    Person.userInteractionEnabled = true

    self.mainImageView.addSubview(Person)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)


}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "detailImage") {
        let imageVC = (segue.destinationViewController as! ImageViewController)

        imageVC.image = image
    }
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    let touch : UITouch! = event.allTouches()?.first

    location = touch.locationInView(self.mainImageView)

    Person.center = location

}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    let touch : UITouch! = event.allTouches()?.first

    location = touch.locationInView(self.mainImageView)

    Person.center = location

}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let size = CGSizeMake(mainImageView.image!.size.width, mainImageView.image!.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0.0)

    mainImageView.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(mainImageView.frame.origin.x, mainImageView.frame.origin.y, size.width, size.height))
    Person.image?.drawInRect(CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, frontSize.width, frontSize.height))

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //set finalImage to IBOulet UIImageView
    image = newImage

}

}
```

I have a `UIButton` below this `mainImageView` which then performs a segue, so, basically `mainImageView` doesn't have same width and height as main Screen.
The code does work, there is just a little problem. The foreground image (Person) becomes very small compared to its original size and isn't even at the same as the one that I drag it onto.

Comment: Please explain your problem in details. I do not understand what you want

Comment: @AmitSingh trying to combine 2 images by overlapping 1 over another but the foreground images shrinks on the resultant mage

Comment: What size do you want for the foreground image?

Comment: I've implemented your code and not finding any shrink to the foreground image

Comment: Are you setting the image view to full width and height of screen?

Comment: You mean background image?

Comment: Yes, the back image

Comment: yes, foreground image not shrinking

Comment: But, I am not setting the background IV to full view' width and height. It's smaller than that. I have to make it relative somehow, which I am trying, so far, no result.

Comment: Previously background image was not full screen, but yes it was bigger than the foreground image

Comment: But, I am not getting the required result.

Comment: can you create a video and send me to amitksingh2806 skype id

Comment: I will try that tomorrow

Comment: I found the solution. Had to do with imageView's width and height.

Comment: Post your solution as answer

Comment: It was in storyboard and I corrected foreground image's position by changing "location.x, location.y" to "Person.frame.origin.x, Person.frame.origin.y".